# sas proc lifereg unlogged response

Tags: sas, survival-analysis, model-fitting

I performed SAS PROC LIFEREG on a dataset, assuming the baseline distribution to be generalized gamma. The commands I used are:

```
proc lifereg data=work;
model time*censor(0)=mqlp bsid mkd1 mkd1x  mkd2 szsd stkv turn / distribution=gamma ;
run;
```

And I got the fit statistics:

```
Fit Statistics
-2 Log Likelihood   4668.169
AIC (smaller is better) 4690.169
AICC (smaller is better)    4690.209
BIC (smaller is better) 4764.887

Fit Statistics (Unlogged Response)
-2 Log Likelihood   9351.562
Gamma AIC (smaller is better)   9373.562
Gamma AICC (smaller is better)  9373.602
Gamma BIC (smaller is better)   9448.280
```

Why the unlogged repsonse has different likelihood from the logged one? What's the difference between these two cases?